# Stopping Python from attempting to add \r\n to a filename?

Tags: python

How do I stop Python from attempting to add \r\n to the filename?
I am not sure how to make this work. I have gotten this to work on another attachment list but I just don't see the answer to this one. *This is my first time working with Python*

I have tried using R(RAW) command but it only works for the foldername.

Filename "AR Invoice_26316.pdf" --> Receving "AR\r\n Invoice_26316.pdf"

I can not change the filename.

This is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 43, in <module>
    fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'C:/test/AR\r\n Invoice_26316.pdf'
```

Reusing script:

```
import email, getpass, imaplib, os

detach_dir = "C:/test/"
user = "xxxxxxxxx"
pwd = "xxxxxxxxx"

# connecting to the gmail imap server
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
m.login(user,pwd)
m.select("No-Reply") # here you a can choose a mail box like INBOX instead
# use m.list() to get all the mailboxes

resp, items = m.search(None, "ALL") 
items = items[0].split() # getting the mails id

for emailid in items:
    resp, data = m.fetch(emailid, "(RFC822)") # fetching the mail, "`(RFC822)`" means "get the whole stuff", but you can ask for headers only, etc
    email_body = data[0][1] # getting the mail content
    mail = email.message_from_string(email_body) # parsing the mail content to get a mail object

    #Check if any attachments at all
    if mail.get_content_maintype() != 'multipart':
        continue

    print "["+mail["From"]+"] :" + mail["Subject"]

    # we use walk to create a generator so we can iterate on the parts and forget about the recursive headach
    for part in mail.walk():
        # multipart are just containers, so we skip them
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue

        # is this part an attachment ?
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue

        filename = part.get_filename()
        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)

        #Check if its already there
        if not os.path.isfile(att_path) :
            # finally write the stuff
            fp = open(att_path, 'wb')
            fp.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))
            fp.close()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, I would recommend using pathlib instead of the os module for file path manipulation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
        filename = part.get_filename().replace("\r\n", "")
        att_path = os.path.join(detach_dir, filename)
```